# Issue with variable defining

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I execute the following code, I get the error "player_normal_defense is not defined". I get what the issue is but if I had to define the variable inside the Defense function, it would be totally pointless since the variable stores the initial defense value for further usage. How should I solve this?

```
import random
import sys
import os
import time

from Entity import *

class Battle():

    def Attack(self, attacker, defender):
        damage = attacker.atk - defender.dif
        defender.hp -= damage

    def Defense(self, owner, defending, entity_id):
        defense_boost = 10
        if defending:
            owner.dif += defense_boost
        elif not defending:
            if entity_id == 1:
                owner.dif = player_normal_defense
            elif entity_id == 2:
                owner.dif = enemy_normal_defense

    def Turn_Generator(self, pl, en):
        turns_list = []
        speed_product = pl.speed / en.speed
        first_speed_product = speed_product
        if speed_product >= 1:
            turns_list.append("P")
        elif speed_product < 1:
            turns_list.append("E")

        while len(turns_list) < 100:
            if speed_product >= 2:
                turns_list.append("P")
                turns_list.append("P")
                speed_product = 0.6
            elif speed_product < 2 and speed_product >= 1:
                turns_list.append("P")
                if first_speed_product <= 0.5:
                    speed_product = first_speed_product
                else:
                    speed_product = 0.6
            elif speed_product <= 0.5:
                turns_list.append("E")
                turns_list.append("E")
                speed_product = 1
            elif speed_product > 0.5 and speed_product < 1:
                turns_list.append("E")
                if first_speed_product >= 2:
                    speed_product = first_speed_product
                else:
                    speed_product = 1
        return turns_list

    def Combat(self, player, enemy):
        turn_counter = 1
        player_normal_defense = player.dif
        enemy_normal_defense = enemy.dif
        fighting = True
        while fighting:
            print(f"Turn {turn_counter}")
            turns = self.Turn_Generator(player, enemy)
            for current_turn in turns:
                print(f"""
======================
YOUR HPs:   ENEMY HPs:
{player.hp}         {enemy.hp}
======================""")
                print(f"""
================
Current turn: {current_turn}
================


===========
Next turns:
 {turns[1]}
 {turns[2]}
 {turns[3]}
 {turns[4]}
===========
""")
                if current_turn == "P":
                    choice = input("1. Attack\n2. Defend\n")
                    if choice == "1":
                        self.Attack(player, enemy)
                        self.Defense(player, False, 1)
                    elif choice == "2":
                        self.Defense(player, True, 1)
                    else:
                        print("Lost your chance!")
                elif current_turn == "E":
                    enemy_choice = random.randint(1, 2)
                    if enemy_choice == 2:
                        print("He attacks you!")
                        self.Attack(enemy, player)
                        self.Defense(enemy, False, 2)
                    else:
                        print("He defends himself.")
                        self.Defense(enemy, True, 2)
                time.sleep(3)
                os.system("clear")
                turns.pop(0)
                if player.hp <= 0:
                    print("You died!")
                    sys.exit(0)
                elif enemy.hp <= 0:
                    print("YOU WON!")
                    fighting = False
                break
                turn_counter += 1
```

Comment: I would advice to use a constructor in your class: [__init__ explained](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-difference-between-self-and-init-methods-in-python-Class#:~:text=__init__%20method,the%20attributes%20of%20the%20class.)

Comment: The scope of the `player_normal_defense` variable is within its function (Combat). Once you try to access it from `Defense` it is another scope. I think you should look for OOP and classes which will ease what you try to achieve.

Comment: Why not make `player_normal_defense` an attribute of the class rather than merely a local variable of one of the methods? Also, please fix the indentation of your code. As is, what you posted isn't valid Python.

Comment: It looks like you want `player_normal_defense` to be a global variable that is accessible throughout your module. If that is what you want then your code should declare it as such: `global player_normal_defense`  in every function that needs it.

Comment: Thanks you all! I have not great understanding of scopes. I thought it was an issue related to the order of function defining, since the Defense method uses the variable before it gets declared.

Comment: @cicciolucchini Can you fix the indentation of your methods? The lack of indentation  makes them look like top level functions.

Comment: @Axe319 Done that! But now it doesn't highlight properly ahahahahah. Sorry but I am a total beginner, I am getting into this in spare time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When entity is defending, instead of running a Defence function to add a bonus to entitys Defence score only if it is true, I would just not run the Defence function when attacking. When entity is defending then you can run the Defense (Bonus) function as;

```
def Defending():
    defence_boost = 10
```

in the decision check;

```
if choice == "2":
    self.dif += Defending()
```

One issue I believe you will have with the code is that you are raising the entitys .dif stat with each occurrence of defending. This means that when this has cycled multiple times the base dif may be too high for any attackers damage to do anything to the opponents health.

Comment: That was exactly why I thought of running Defense with a False parameter when attacking, cause if not the boost to .dif would stack, creating exactly the problem you stated.

Comment: If it helps with cleaning it up a bit you could just set the player.dif and enemy.dif to the saved variable player_normal_defense and enemy_normal_defense at the end of each turn counter and that would save having to call the variable anywhere else in your code other than in the Battle function and this would resolve any issues trying to call the variable in other functions.

Comment: It would not fulfill the purpose of defending since you would defend but have the .dif restored to normal before the enemy turn. Anyway thanks for the advice!